# Best way to store aggregated values

Tags: sql, nosql, aggregation, nosql-aggregation

We need to store aggregated values for different accounts which summarise various numbers on Month/Year basis. These numbers would be updated each time the data is updated (usually once or twice every 24 hours).

I'm expecting the data to be the results of PIVOT functions e.g.:

```
Year    Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2011    0   0   0   0   0   0   95  33  34  24  36  52
```

Each account will need different aggregates e.g. "Count Of Customers", "Count Of Orders" and "Value Of Sales" and I'm not sure whether it would be best to add a key to the data or use separate tables e.g.:

```
Year    Key        Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2011    CntOrders  0   0   0   0   0   0   95  33  34  24  36  52
2011    CntCust    0   0   0   0   0   0   95  33  34  24  36  52
2011    ValOrders  0   0   0   0   0   0   95  33  34  24  36  52
```

Or
dbo.CountOfOrders

```
Year    Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2011    0   0   0   0   0   0   95  33  34  24  36  52
```

dbo.ValueOfOrders

```
Year    Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2011    0   0   0   0   0   0   95  33  34  24  36  52
```

I've read a number of posts suggesting both NoSQL and SQL Server so I'm not sure which way we should go or how to decide.

We can't justify a dedicated cube at the moment but I'm wondering if it would be better to store the values in a NoSQL database or whether we should stick with SQL Server?

Comment: Why not create views that do this "on-the-fly"?

Comment: We can't due to time constraints, the sheer volume of the data means that running these queries can take minutes -and not only that, once the point has passed (e.g. last year) the data doesn't change but will be accessed frequently

Comment: What about indexed views that are refreshed on a regular basis?

Comment: Depending on your SQL product, you *may* be able to construct an indexed (SQL Server) or Materialized (Oracle) view (other products may have similar means). I know in SQL Server you wouldn't be able to do the pivot directly in the view (but you could build a view *based* on the indexed view that does the pivot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll stick with SQL. However, if you are worried about the time to rebuild such PIVOT table, don't, because you don't have to necessarily build a table with unique "key".

Build it with key + process datetime and just append it to the main pivot. So during creation of the incrementals it will be bounded by your transaction timestamp (begin and end). There should be much bloat. If there is, you can collapse the process dates in a weekend job.

Comment: Thanks Rob, we'll stick with SQL for the time being, the process of updating is fine, we know when the data changes so can trigger at that point. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Set up a job to run stored procedures that insert data into tables.

Store the data like Account,Year,Month,Value

Use views of these tables for reporting multiple aggregates.

Definitely stick with SQL. There is no reason to add technical overhead for such a simple task.

Comment: Thanks BeachAndBytes, the update isn't an issue it's more the mechanism e.g. what format to store the tables in.